# Why am I unable to set "OwnerDrawFixed" for "CheckedListBox" in Powershell?

Tags: winforms, powershell

I am trying to find a solution to this issue since 10 days and nothing.

I need to be able to create a Checkedlistbox form and to set "OwnerDrawFixed" to that, but it always stays at "Normal".

Why?

$checkedListBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.CheckedListBox

$checkedListBox.DrawMode = [System.Windows.Forms.DrawMode]::OwnerDrawFixed

$checkedListBox.DrawMode

Normal

The reason is ask that is because I really want to find a solution to my issue :

[Add checkboxes to Listbox with Powershell Windows Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27445370/add-checkboxes-to-listbox-with-powershell-windows-forms)

Thanks 1000x in advance if you have ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with powershell. Simply CheckedListBox doesn't supports [DrawMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.drawmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property.

It exist there just because it is inherited from its base class. A classic example of [LSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) violation.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So, there is no way to have a Winform with checkboxes and colour some specific individual items? The Listbox colours items but no checkboxes, and the CheckedListbox doesn't colour items but with checkboxes.

Comment: @expirat001 May be [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18725111/can-i-use-a-drawitem-event-handler-with-a-checkedlistbox) can help you.